# Ext JS combobox doesnt allow ctrl + c on comma separated values

Tags: javascript, extjs, clipboard

I am not able to use ctrl + c on a ComboBox when I have a comma separated values in it. I can use it for a single value though.

This is working fine:

[image]

I have an issue with this one.

This is not working:

[image]

Comment: Works for me: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fdl

Comment: I checked this ..It seems to work fine on fiddle but I wonder why the behaviour is different in my application. Its really confusing. @Alexander

Comment: Can't say from your screenshots.

Comment: I know its not that self explanatory but I dont have any option to show it live. The issue is, once i have multiple values in the combo box and if i select all and press Ctrl + C, the content is copied but the selected text gets hidden and its not visible. I can paste it there but thats too undesirable for our client. looking for a proper solution.